# NodaTime - Errors after time switch

Tags: nodatime

Yesterday Uruguay changed their clocks, and now I keep seeing exceptions when converting specific times for their timezone:

```
ERROR   Exception: - DateTime ConvertTimeToUtc(DateTime, String)    (05/10/2014 02:31:00, America/Montevideo)
NodaTime.SkippedTimeException: Specified argument was out of the range of valid values.
Parameter name: Local time 05/10/2014 02:31:00 is invalid in time zone America/Montevideo
```

I understand how a local time can be invalid:

*"For example, suppose the time zone goes forward at 2am, so the second after 01:59:59 becomes 03:00:00. In that case, local times such as 02:30:00 never occur."*

However, what I don't understand (and I probably need more coffee), is why NodaTime is not accounting for this? Should it not be aware that 02:31 is now an invalid local time - or should I be doing additional handling to account for this?

Functions I'm calling:

```
var timeZone = DateTimeZoneProviders.Tzdb[timezoneName];
var localTime = LocalDateTime.FromDateTime(timeToConvert).InZoneStrictly(timeZone);;
return DateTime.SpecifyKind(localTime.ToDateTimeUtc(), DateTimeKind.Utc);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, it *is* aware that it's an invalid local time - which is why when you specifically ask it to convert that local time into UTC, it throws an exception. It's roughly equivalent to calling `Math.sqrt(-1)`.

The [`InZoneStrictly`](http://nodatime.org/1.3.x/api/html/M_NodaTime_LocalDateTime_InZoneStrictly.htm) call you're making specifically throws an exception on either ambiguous or skipped times. If you use [`InZoneLeniently`](http://nodatime.org/1.3.x/api/html/M_NodaTime_LocalDateTime_InZoneLeniently.htm) you won't get an exception, but it may not give you the result you want. Or, you could use [`LocalDateTime.InZone(DateTimeZone, ZoneLocalMappingResolver)`](http://nodatime.org/1.3.x/api/html/M_NodaTime_LocalDateTime_InZone.htm) which will allow you to map invalid local date/time values however you want.

As side-notes:

- Your `localTime` variable is a `ZonedDateTime`, so the name is a bit misleading
- You don't need to call `SpecifyKind` - `ToDateTimeUtc` will always return a `DateTime` with a kind of `Utc`, hence the name.

Comment: Thanks for your answer John. I've added the functions I'm calling to the question. I now understand I get the error when converting the local time to UTC, should I be doing something different to get the local time in the first place?

Comment: @FBryant87: It's not really clear what you're trying to achieve, to be honest - where did you get `timeToConvert` from? In some cases it may be reasonable data, e.g. if you have a recurrent event at 2:30am every day... you then need to work out what that means on a day where 2:30am happens 0 or 2 times.

Comment: Thanks I think your updated answer explains it a bit more, I'll read up on InZoneLeniently.

Comment: @FBryant87: Right - I've added a couple more links, too.

Comment: One last quick question about InZoneLeniently Jon:
In this case I can see it returns a UTC date of 5:00am (which is a good "guess"), I'm just wondering if there's a reason it loses the minutes when it 'jumps' forwards?

For example 02:31 doesn't jump to 03:21, it jumps to 03:00

Comment: @FBryant87: It gives you the closest local time after the one you asked for. We've had a feature request to add a resolver which will add an hour instead - but you can already build it with the 1.3 API. Look at the `Resolvers` class.